# In the expression left() = right(), why is right() sequenced first?

Tags: c++, c++17, assignment-operator

In C++, the expression `left() = right()` evaluates

1. `right()`
2. `left()`

in that sequence. The `right()` goes first, as has been discussed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52762511/1275653)

I cannot think of a reason for `right()` to go first. Can you? I presume that there exists a reason. Otherwise, the standard would hardly say what it says, but consider: `right()` will return some result. At the machine-code level, does the CPU not need to know where to put the result `right()` will return before asking `right()` to return it?

If you happen to know what the standard committee was thinking (because you were in the room or have read the memo), that's great: I'd like to read your answer. However, my actual question is more modest. All I want to know is whether there exists a plausible reason and what that reason might be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In addition to the unintuitive result when doing what Brian showed:

```
#include <map>
int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    m[0] = m.size(); // before C++17 m[0] could be 0 or 1 - it was implementation defined
}
```

If we take a the same map but do:

```
#include <map>
int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    m[0] = Right(); // Right() may throw
}
```

If `Right()` throws:

Before C++17 you could get a default constructed element in `m[0]` (left to right) or `m[0]` wouldn't be created at all (right to left). In C++17 `m[0]` will not get created at all.

Answer (score 24):

In the proposal [P0145](https://wg21.link/P0145) that introduced this evaluation order, the authors gave the following example:

```
#include <map>
int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    m[0] = m.size();
}
```

In this situation, left-to-right evaluation would give 1, whereas right-to-left evaluation would give 0. Having the result be 0, thanks to right-to-left evaluation, corresponds more closely to our intuition that the value that should be assigned is the one that existed immediately before the assignment expression was evaluated.